# What do we know about "co-choice" functions?

Tags: set-theory

This is not the question.

I have a certain property relating pairs of functions $f,g:X\to Y$ to "nice" covers of $X$ and $Y$. There is an interesting relationship between this property, the functions mapping each member of a "nice" cover to its image, and choice functions mapping covers to their respective spaces by which a vaguely analogous property holds for functions between covers.

I believe that this relationship might become clearer if I tried replacing choice functions with "co-choice" functions - that is, functions $C:A\to\mathcal F$, where $A\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal F$, such that $a\in C(a)$ for all $a\in A$ (in the application these would be maps from a suitable space to a "nice" cover.)

---

This is the question.

What do we know about "co-choice" functions?

With choice functions, the picture is very clear; I have set-theoretic, topological, algebraic, and combinatorial tools to work with. While there's an obvious duality between choice and co-choice functions (most notably, the inverse of one is the other, when bijective), I haven't been able to relate co-choice functions to well-known objects or properties in the same way.

They don't relate directly to coproducts in the same way that choice functions relate to products, their relationship with order is not obvious, the implications of various forms of "co-choice" are unclear, and the combinatorics are... well I've only just had the idea now, give me a moment, yeh?

I haven't found anything by searching, but I also don't have a name for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you please avoid using $A$ and $\mathcal{A}$ for two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axiom of co-choice is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Assume the axiom of choice.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a non-empty set of non-empty sets.  For each $a\in \bigcup\mathcal F$ define $G_a=\{F\in\mathcal F\colon a\in F\}$.  Let $\mathcal G=\{G_a\colon a\in\bigcup\mathcal F\}$.  Let $g\colon\mathcal{G}\to\bigcup\mathcal G$ be a choice function.  Let $h\colon\bigcup F\to\mathcal G$ be the function $h(a)=G_a$.  Then $g\circ h$ is a co-choice function for $\bigcup\mathcal F$.

Assume the axiom of co-choice.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a non-empty set of non-empty sets.  Let $\mathcal G=\{(x,a)\in\mathcal F\times\bigcup\mathcal F\colon x\in \mathcal F\land a\in x\}$ where $(x,a):=\{\{x\},\{x,a\}\}$.  Let $g\colon \bigcup\mathcal G\to \mathcal G$ be a co-choice function.  For each $x\in\mathcal F$, $\{x\}\in\bigcup\mathcal G$ and $g(\{x\})$ is a pair $(x,a)=\{\{x\},\{x,a\}\}$ where $a\in x$.  So letting $f(x)$ be the unique $a$ such that $g(\{x\})=(x,a)$ we get a choice function $f\colon\mathcal F\to\bigcup\mathcal F$.